# Software framework and application framework?

Tags: frameworks, terminology

I was wondering what differences and relations are between [software framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_framework) and [application framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_framework)? The existence of articles for both concepts in Wikipedia confuses me.

Are they both some kind of libraries?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: By their definition, an "application framework" is a subset of all "software framework"s.

Comment: Thanks! How is that a subset?

Answer (score 2):

Not all software is an application.

Some frameworks support development of an application. For example, the Eclipse Rich Client Platform is an application platform.

Others support development of other types of software, such as middleware.

Answer (score 0):

**Application framework is a type of software framework.**

No.Software framework and Application framework is not the same. Application framework is a type of software framework. Application frameworks are often used for  development of general GUI applications but some other frameworks like Enterprise architecture framework(Development of enterprise applications), Oracle ADF(Provide visual and declarative approaches to java EE development), and Cactus computing frameworks(Used for scientific computing with higher performance) can also be considered as software frameworks.

Since not all the application frameworks are software frameworks.